# Как сделать редирект вне диапозона ip

Tags: php, ip

Добрый день! 
Интересует вопрос как сделать редирект на сайт айпишников, которые находятся вне диайпозона ip, которые имеют доступ к данной странице или сайту.
Нужно, что-то похожее на это:

```
$location = 'http://www.google.com/';

$range_low = ip2long("80.87.206.35");
$range_high = ip2long("80.87.206.38");

$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if ($ip <= $range_low && $ip => $range_high) {
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: '.$location);  
}

else {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос, но может быть так?

```
$location = 'http://www.google.com/';

$range_low = ip2long("80.87.206.35");
$range_high = ip2long("80.87.206.38");

$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if ($ip <= $range_low || $ip >= $range_high) {
  header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
  header ('Location: '.$location);  
} else {

}
```

Comment: именно так и хотел, не до конца разобрался) спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Так как у нас меняются только последние значения, то я предлагаю все это дело парсить и проверять.

```
function checkIP ($user_ip, $ip_begin, $ip_end) {
 return (ip2long($user_ip)>=ip2long($ip_begin) && ip2long($user_ip)<=ip2long($ip_end));
}

$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
echo checkIP($user_ip, '93.158.155.128', '93.158.155.191') ? 'IP внутри подсети' : 'Нет';
```

Comment: спасибо! попробую тоже ваш вариант

Answer (score 0):

Потребовалось также сделать для нескольких диапозонов, в результате сделал так:

```
$location = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
$location2 = file_get_contents('http://www.ya.ru');

$range_low = ip2long("128.140.172.0");
$range_high = ip2long("128.140.175.255");

$range_low2 = ip2long("94.100.184.0");
$range_high2 = ip2long("94.100.191.255");

$range_low3 = ip2long("94.100.176.0");
$range_high3 = ip2long("94.100.183.255");

$ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


if (($ip < $range_low or $ip > $range_high) ^ ($ip < $range_low2 or $ip > $range_high2) ^ ($ip < $range_low3 or $ip > $range_high3)) {
echo $location;  // Если не входит в диапозон

} else {
echo $location2; // Если входит в диапозон
```